# How do I set the 'page width' in Haskell using ansi-wl-pprint library?

Tags: text, haskell

I am currently using the ansi-wl-pprint library. The width function is undocumented, but I need to set it so that the width of the page is 80 characters instead of the default 100.

How do I do this? Function width accepts a Doc as its first argument and then a function from Int -> Doc as the second argument. There are no instructions on what this function is meant to do.

Comment: Whenever I try to format it as a "column" of text, nothing is changed. I want to output a document left-justified with a ragged right edge and word-wrap.

Comment: It sounds like you want "paragraph formatting" not "pretty printing". I'm not sure there is a library for this, though there are "illustrative" implementations available - please see my other comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided ansi-wl-pprint follows wl-pprint, you want to use the renderPretty function to render the Doc to a different width and possibly use a different ribbon-fraction (here 0.7), something like this should work:

```
show100 :: Doc -> String
show100 d = displayS (renderPretty 0.7 100 d) ""
```

See the last section of the manual on Daan Leijen's old website:

http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/pprint/pprint.pdf

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. I basically want left-justified text with a ragged right edge and word-wrap. Hence the need to tell it what my page size is.

Comment: Probably you don't want a pretty printer then. "Pretty printers" essentially print with nesting - think source code formatting. They are not paragraph formatters. I don't know if there is a library for paragraph formatting. Paragraph formatting has been a topic for the "Algebra of Programming" group - there's code in the link below, but the paper's subject is the functional algorithm so it might not be so accessible.

http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/oucl/work/jeremy.gibbons/publications/bridging.ps.gz

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [definition](https://github.com/batterseapower/ansi-wl-pprint/blob/master/Text/PrettyPrint/ANSI/Leijen.hs) of the `fill` and `width` functions, it seems the second argument to `width` gets called with the width of its first arg and produces a document accordingly.

```
fill :: Int -> Doc -> Doc
fill f d = width d (\w ->
                  if (w >= f) then empty
                              else text (spaces (f - w)))

width :: Doc -> (Int -> Doc) -> Doc
width d f = column (\k1 -> d <> column (\k2 -> f (k2 - k1)))
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps. I've tried most combinations and nothing seems to work